# Neo4j + Jotm migration, absent transaction's classes/interfaces

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, data-migration, transactional, jotm

I'm using Neo4j 1.8.9 + Jotm with ALRubinger's solution : [How to enlist XAResource with existing Transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824518/how-to-enlist-xaresource-with-existing-transaction), everything working fine, but few days ago I started migration to Neo4j 2.2.1 and came across to the next problem - neo4j-kernel.jar have no more:
**TransactionManagerProvider,AbstractTransactionManager,TransactionStateFactory** etc.
The classes was deleted from 2.1.8 version, I'm tried to use 
Spring Data Neo4j » 3.3.0.RELEASE but they use neo4j-kernel 2.1.7 and it's the same implementation that i had before.

Where did they moved all the classes/interfaces? Another jar? More simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JTA as a internal implementation detail has been removed in Neo4j, quoting from the [release notes](http://neo4j.com/release-notes/neo4j-2-2-0/):

> The use of separate transactions logs for the graph and the indexes, co-ordinated by an XA system, has been replaced by a singular transactional management and one unified transaction log. This substantially reduces resource overhead and improves scalability. Note that as result of this, the previously exposed XA and JTA functionalities have been removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So , If I have understood correctly there is no way to do two face commit?
I'm working with two db's (Neo4j & Mysql) how it's possible to work with two (or more) databases without base XA functionality?

Comment: @SerDJ did you find a solution?